# string indices must be integers when use string as list

Tags: python

I faced a compile error in my python script as following:

```
formula = "ASD"
start = 0
end = 2
print(formula, start, end, type(start), type(end))
print(formula[start, end])
```

the output is:

```
ASD 0 2 <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(formula[start, end])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

But start, end is int, so strange!

Answer (score 3):

The syntax to slice is with `:` not with `,`

```
>>> print(formula[start:end])
AS
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, slicing is written like

```
formula[start:end]
```

The error in your original code is because

```
formula[start, end]
```

is being interpreted as

```
formula[(start, end)]
```

So the string index is a tuple, instead of an `int` or slice.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be performing a slicing operation, in order to do this you need to use `:` and not `,`:

```
formula[start:end]
```

Demo:

```
formula = "ASD"
start = 0
end = 2
print(formula, start, end, type(start), type(end))
print(formula[start:end])
```

output:

```
ASD 0 2 <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
AS
```